# When popen performs status check on service that dosen't exist error no results returned

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am attempting to use `subprocess.Popen()` to read a service status.

If I get an `unrecognized service error` the value, while printed to the screen, is not saved to `out` or `err` for later viewing.

If the service does exist, "is running" gets saved to the `out` value. I would like to accomplish the same results when the unrecognized error is encountered.

I have tried using `subprocess.check_output` but it is unrecognized.

If I use an existing service it works as desired.

My code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['service','PretendService','status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out,err = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pipe `stderr` as well as `stdout`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['service','PretendService','status'], 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
# Now err will have your error message
```

Comment: ... that was painfully simple